# How exactly is include/require resolved in PHP?

Tags: php, include

I have a file `include/vars.php`, relative to the server root:

```php
<?php

$SOME_VAR = "...";
```

and a file defining a function `include/funcs.php`:

```php
<?php

require "vars.php";

function my_func() {
    echo(var_dump($SOME_VAR));
}
```

then a file `endpoint.php` supposed to call `my_func`:

```php
<?php

require "include/funcs.php";

my_func();
```

I would expect this to output `...` but I get the error

```
Undefined variable SOME_VAR in include/funcs.php
```

when I move the `require` inside the function, it works. But not when I add a `require` to `endpoint.php`:

```php
// include/funcs.php
<?php

function my_func() {
    require "vars.php"; // works
    echo(var_dump($SOME_VAR));
}
```

```php
// endpoint.php
<?php

require "include/vars.php"; // does not work
require "include/funcs.php";


my_func();
```

So how is the require statement actually resolved? I would expect when the imported file includes `vars.php`, the variables are also visible in the importing file. If not, I would have thought at least importing the variable first will make it visible to functions imported later on. However only importing the variable *inside* the function itself works.

Is this correct or am I doing something wrong? Maybe it has to do with the directory structure? How could I debug this?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with require/include - `$SOME_VAR = "..."; function my_func() { echo(var_dump($SOME_VAR)); } my_func();` all written in one and the same file to begin with, would have given you the exact same error. _Variable scope_ is the issue.

Comment: `echo(var_dump())` is nonsense, btw. - `var_dump` itself already writes to the output buffer. It doesn't have a return value (which echo then _could_ output, if it did.)

Comment: Agreed, this is about the basics of variable scope, and has nothing to do with `include` etc. You'd have the same problem trying to use any kind of variable when it's not in scope. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php